# Какая API (библиотека) для работы с картами существует наподобие Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api, google-maps, карты

Посоветуйте API(библиотеку) работы с картами для JS. Что-то наподобие Google Maps. Что сейчас больше используют?

Comment: Посоветую Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Яндекс.Карт — это набор web-служб, которые позволяют использовать картографические данные и технологии Яндекса

Подробнее о них можно узнать по ссылкам:

- [JavaScript API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/?from=SO)
- [HTTP Геокодер](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/?from=SO)
- [HTTP API Поиска по организациям](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/?from=SO) (геопоиска)
- [Static API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/staticapi/?from=SO)
- [Конструктор и Виджет Яндекс.Карт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/mapstools/?from=SO)
- [Официальная документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/?from=SO)
- [Площадка для общения про API Яндекс-карт](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/?from=SO)

Comment: Что можете сказать о:
1. Open Streer Maps
2. Leaflet
3. MapBox

Comment: @Oswald, ничего не могу сказать, т. к. с ними не знаком. Но советую поискать в поисковике страницы на русском о них. К примеру, вот о [Open Streer Maps](https://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&as_q=Open+Street+Maps&lr=lang_ru).